# POST variables not passing to action correctly

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm working with a page that has multiple `<form>` tags in it. One of the forms in question looks something like:

```
<form name="frm6910" action="ind_profile.php?ind_id=" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update">
  <input type="hidden" name="auto_change" value="1">
```

But, when I go to `var_dump()`  the POST variables in `ind_profile.php`, my array is empty. I'm not sure how to provide more insight on this question, but I'm looking for possibilities on why POST variables may not be passing correctly.

Would having multiple `<form>` tags within one page be the cause of incorrectly passing values?

As requested, here is a snipit evaluating one of the POST variables:

```
ob_start()
require('crm_common.php'); 

var_dump($_POST);


switch(@$_POST['action']) { 
case 'update':
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sharing the code in ind_profile.php that gets the variables might help.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, be sure you don't already have another <form> opened with different action, method etc. Be sure to close that one before opening another. Sometimes it's easy to overlook it, and makes debugging rather tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, no content gets sent until the output buffer (ob_start()) is either flushed or closed. See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) for details on output buffering.

---

The multiple forms shouldn't be an issue.

I noticed you start an output buffer. Do you get the content or flush it out afterwards? Try to do

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
```

As the first thing in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sylverdrag, but the $_POST array is still empty. This is older code, and I am not very familiar with the `ob_start()`, but I don't believe I retrieve or flush it.

Comment: @etm124 Oh, then that's it. What ob_start() does is to hold any output to the screen until it is either flushed or stored in a variable and reused. If you don't flush it or get the content, the script will not output anything apart from the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you posting from a specific submit button?

```
if(isset($_POST['nameOfSubmitButtom'])){
  var_dump();
}
```

Comment: I am not. I've added code to show you how I am evaluating a POST variable.